# Help in solving an optimization problem

Tags: polynomials, global-optimization, taylor-expansion

I have a simple optimization problem;
I already know the answer but I don't know how to prove it!
Assuming we have a series of positive real numbers,
$$ x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_n, $$
we want to find a series
$$ y_1, y_2, y_3, ..., y_n $$
that minimizes the goal function
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}$$
while ensuring
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i = 1 .$$

I already know the answer is
$$ y_i = \cfrac{x_i}{ \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j} ,$$

but I don't know the way to reach the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The lagrangian

$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}+\lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i - 1\right)
$$

has as stationary points, the solutions for

$$
\cases{
\nabla_{y_i}L = -\frac{x_i^2}{y_i^2}+\lambda=0\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i - 1 = 0
}
$$

From the first equation we have

$$
-\frac{x_i^2}{y_i}+\lambda y_i = 0\Rightarrow -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_i^2}{y_i}+\lambda = 0
$$

then

$$
-\frac{x_i^2}{y_i^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x_k^2}{y_k}=0
$$

Now you can check if your solution works.